# How to find the missing numbers in sequence SAS

Tags: sas

In SAS, how can I find the missing numbers in my 'Number' col for each 'ID'?

For example, ID 1003 has a max of 6 and is clearly missing Number 5.  I have about 4000 rows to look at so doing this manually is not going to happen.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  I'm stumped.

`ID Number
1002    2
1002    1
1003    6
1003    4
1003    3
1003    2
1003    1
1005    4
1005    3
1005    2
1005    1
1007    1
1009    3
1009    2
1009    1`

Comment: Please include code including what you have tried so far to solve this problem.  Directly asking for code is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without writing the code for you, here's an outline of one method...

1. Sort your data by ID (ascending) and Number (descending)
2. Take the first record per ID (giving the max Number)
3. Iterate from that max Number down to 1, output each iteration
4. Re-sort by ID and Number (ascending)

Answer (score -1):

I ran the following code after using DATALINES to input the data you provided in your question.

First Transpose the Data by ID:

```
proc sort data=mydata; by id; run;
proc transpose data =mydata  out=transposed  prefix=number_;
by ID;
var number;
id number;
run;
```

This next step just re-orders the variable names, the retain statement doesn't do anything else in this step.

```
data transposed_and_ordered;
retain id _name_ number_1 number_2 number_3 number_4 number_5 number_6;
set transposed;
run;
```

The two steps above (along with the DATALINES input step) yielded the following dataset transposed_and_ordered:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ID   | NAME    | number_1 | number_2  | number_3  | number_4  | number_6 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1002 | number  | 1        | 2         |           |           |          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1003 | number  | 1        | 2         |3          |4          |6         |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1005 | number  | 1        | 2         |3          |4          |          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1007 | number  | 1        |           |           |           |          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1009 | number  | 1        | 2         |3          |           |          |
```